# Tips for understanding the Pumping Lemma for Context-Free Languages

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I'm having a hard time wrapping the idea in my head. Can anyone explain this as different from Sipser's perspective?

(I saw one discussion in reddit but it's for regular languages)
https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/1pnjrp/the_pumping_lemma/

Comment: Did you try the usual translation into competitive game between one player representing $\forall$ statements and another player representing $\exists$ statements?

Comment: I have seen the ∀ and ∃ version of the lemma but haven't heard of the competitive game. Can you tell more about it?

Comment: Reproducing textbook chapters is no good for this platform. Get another book, or try to formulate a more specific question! You can also check [our reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/843#843), and the question tagged [tag:pumping-lemma].

Answer (score 2):

One way of looking at the pumping lemma is in terms of the *pumping game*, a two-player game parametrized by an infinite language $L$. The two players are the *Prover* and *Challenger*, and the game goes as follows:

1. Prover picks an integer $n$.
2. Challenger picks a word $w \in L$ of length at least $n$.
3. Prover chooses a decomposition $w = xyz$ such that $|xy| \leq n$ and $|y| \ge 1$.
4. Challenger chooses an integer $i$.
5. If $xy^iz \in L$ then Prover wins, otherwise Challenger wins.

The pumping lemma states that:

> If $L$ is regular then Prover has a winning strategy.

The pumping lemma is often used in the contrapositive:

> If Challenger has a winning strategy then $L$ is not regular.

---

Here is an example: we will show that Challenger has a winning strategy for the language $L = \{a^nb^n : n \geq 0\}$.

In response to Prover's choice of $n$, Challenger chooses the word $w = a^n b^n$. In response to Prover's choice of a decomposition $w = xyz$ such that $|xy| \leq n$ and $|y| \geq 1$, Challenger chooses $i=0$. Then $xy^iz = a^{n-|y|}b^n \notin L$, and so Challenger wins.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply an application of a well-known correspondence between [logic and games](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-games/) to the statement of [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages#Formal_statement).

First notice that for any statement of the form:
$$
S = \exists a_1 \ldotp \forall b_1 \ldotp \exists a_2 \ldotp \forall b_2 \ldotp \ldots \exists a_n \ldotp \forall b_n \ldotp p(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\ldots a_n,b_n)
$$
Here, truth value of $p$ is a function of variables $a_1,b_2,\ldots,a_n,b_n$.
There is a corresponding (two-player, zero-sum, extensive-form) game $G_S$ where

- $\exists$-player wins when the statement $p$ is **true**
- $\forall$-player wins when the statement $p$ is **false**
- The players take alternating turns **instantiating** the value of variables in order of $a_1, b_1, \ldots ,a_n,b_n$ starting with the $\exists$-player.

The statement $S$ is:

- true exactly when $\exists$-player has a winning strategy
- false exactly when $\forall$-player has a winning strategy

For the explicit application of this translation for pumping lemma, please see [Yuval Filmus's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/81710/4705).